# Is it possible to do multiple SQL select statements within one query? Both select statements would be on the same table

Tags: sql, join

This is probably due to my limited SQL knowledge, but I'm attempting to obtain data using a statement like this:

```
SELECT hostname 
FROM mytable 
WHERE hostname NOT LIKE '%obl%' 
    AND group NOT IN ('group1','group2','group3','group4','group5','group6','group7')
    AND osname LIKE '%Windows%' 
    AND hostname NOT LIKE 'nic%'
```

I realize that is probably a very bad statement, but it has worked so far. In the beginning I exclude entries where hostname isn't like "obl". I have another query like this:

```
SELECT hostname 
FROM mytable 
WHERE hostname LIKE '%obl%' 
    AND group IN ('group9','group0')
```

From what I understand, **joins** wouldn't be used in this case, since both queries are on the same table (although my knowledge of joins is very limited). I'm accessing this database via a webservice, and I'm not certain what kind of database it is.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I could get the values from both queries in one query?

Comment: What kind of the output do you expect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a UNION statement.

```
SELECT hostname FROM mytable  
WHERE hostname  
    NOT LIKE '%obl%' AND 
    group NOT IN ('group1','group2','group3','group4','group5','group6','group7')  
    AND osname LIKE '%Windows%' 
    AND hostname not LIKE 'nic%'

UNION

SELECT hostname FROM mytable 
WHERE hostname 
    LIKE '%obl%' 
    AND group in ('group9','group0')
```

That will do it, but I think you could rethink those where conditions. I'll give it a thought and edit if necessary.

**EDIT:** You can achieve what you are trying to with a single query, no need for the union.

```
SELECT hostname FROM mytable 
WHERE (
    hostname NOT LIKE '%obl%' 
    AND group NOT IN ('group1','group2','group3','group4','group5','group6','group7') 
    AND osname LIKE '%Windows%' 
    AND hostname NOT LIKE 'nic%'
)
OR (
    hostname LIKE '%obl%' 
    AND group IN ('group9','group0')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `union` statement or `OR` condition to combine these two statements.

```
select hostname from mytable where (hostname not like '%obl%' and group not in ('group1','group2','group3','group4','group5','group6','group7') and osname like '%Windows%' and hostname not like 'nic%')
OR
(hostname like '%obl%' and group in ('group9','group0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two WHERE conditions in just one, using OR to apply both of them. Something like this:

```
SELECT hostname FROM mytable WHERE 
(hostname NOT LIKE '%obl%' AND group NOT IN ('group1','group2','group3','group4','group5','group6','group7') AND osname LIKE '%Windows%' AND hostname NOT LIKE 'nic%')
OR
(hostname LIKE '%obl%' AND group IN ('group9','group0')
```

Two points:

- Using uppercase for SQL words makes easier to read the queries.
- Maybe you will have to use SELECT DISTINCT hostname if you want to be sure about not getting the same one repeated.